# Difference between CreateToken and CreateJwtSecurityToken in .NET Core 3

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt

Creating a JWT using the handler's [CreateToken(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler.createtoken?view=azure-dotnet) method is the way I've seen before. However, now, that I have some time extra and poke around, I noticed that one also can use [CreateJwtSecurityToken(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler.createjwtsecuritytoken?view=azure-dotnet) method.

Reading the docs makes me no wiser, because both are said to produce s security web token. The only difference I see is the paramter list and I sense that there's more to it than that (or they'd be overloaded in the same mehtod all of them). The docs are rather brief and I haven't found any "vs" or "difference" when googling.

What are the different purposes of the methods? I'm using .NET Core 3.0 and the token will be bounced around from/to my Angular SPA.

Comment: Well one difference is one produces an implementation of the abstract SecurityToken class (JWTSecurityToken) and the other does not return an impl but rather the abstract SecurityToken itself

Comment: As far as I know there is no significant difference between these two methods. Basically `CreateToken` is an older method from earlier versions of this library and my guess is that the authors of the library wanted to preserve backward compatibility but they also wanted to add a new function with more appropriate name and a few overloads with different set of parameters and return types. It happens here and there especially in .Net Core when they had to port old libs from .Net Framework to .Net Core. Use whatever works better for you.

Comment: @Fabjan That's a wise suggestion. Haven't thought of that reason. What got my poking around and questioning my understanding is that I don't the token to allow me to access my secure endpoint (as asked [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59255124/postman-returns-401-despite-the-valid-token-distributed-for-a-secure-endpoint)). BTW, feel free to take a peek there if you feel like it. You might also post your comment as an answer to be accepted.

Comment: @Fabjan I suggest that you rephrase your comment as an answer to be accepted and remove the comments. It will be more apparent for the future readers what's the conclusion here.